# How to pass same CSV column data to different variable in PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, csv, powershell-2.0

I have CSV file that look something like this

```
Name            Source                   Type

John Smit      http://john.com           OneDrive
John Smit      john.smit@gmail.com       Mailbox
David Parker   http://david.com          OneDrive
David Parker   david.parker@gmail.com    Mailbox
```

and I'm just wondering how can I pass the Name only 1 time and both source at the same time in my $Name, $OneDrive and $Mailbox variable?

For example I'm expecting the output like this in my User_History database table

```
Event_Name    Name        OneDrive            Mailbox
Found         John Smit     http://john.com     john.smit@gmail.com 
Found         David Parker  http://david.com    david.parker@gmail.com
```

I'm kinda stuck so any help or suggestion would be really appreciated.

```
//Pass the value from CSV here
$EventId = Get-EventId 1  // Id 1 = “Found” in List_of_Event table
Set-UsrHistory $EventId.Event_Id $Name $OneDrive $Mailbox


// Get Event value from List_of_Event table
Function Get-EventId($EventId) {
    $query = "select Event_Id from List_of_Events where Event_Id = '$EventId'"
    $result = $db.ExecuteWithResults($query)
    return $result.Tables[0]
}


//Insert to User_History table along with Event value
Function Set-UsrHistory($EvtId, $Name, $OneDrive, $Mailbox) {
    $query = "insert into User_History (Event_Id,Name,OneDrive, Mailboxe) VALUES ('$EvtId','$Name','$OneDrive', '$Mailbox')"
    $query
    $result = $db.ExecuteWithResults($query)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To "pass the name only one time" but get values from different rows merged together (eg: getting both the OneDrive and Mailbox variable), you need to use the `Group-Object` cmdlet to group together items with the same name and from there, you will have 1 name with multiple other values.

You could put the values in variables and use them right away but personally, I prefer separate the part where I put the information together and where I act on it. For this reason, I would create a new list of object that contains each name with their associated mailbox and OneDrive, then do what I want in a second loop.

First, get the initial csv organized (remove duplicate name and get Mailbox / OneDrive together in the same record)

```
$Users = Foreach ($u in $csvdata | Group-Object Name ) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name     = $U.Name
        Mailbox  = $U.Group | Where Type -eq 'MailBox' | Select -First 1 -ExpandProperty Source
        OneDrive = $U.Group | Where Type -eq 'OneDrive' | Select -First 1 -ExpandProperty Source
    }
}
```

Then, iterate through that new `$Users` list and do whatever you want.

```
foreach ($User in $Users) {
     # $SomeEventId is not defined in my example. 
     # This is just to show how you would access each properties of a single $User
     Set-UsrHistory $SomeEventId $User.Name $User.OneDrive $User.Mailbox
}
```

For reference, the `$csvData` I used, based on yours.

```
$csvdata = @'
Name,Source,Type
John Smit,http://john.com,OneDrive
John Smit,john.smit@gmail.com,Mailbox
David Parker,http://david.com,OneDrive
David Parker,david.parker@gmail.com,Mailbox
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

**References**

[Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.2)